# How to segue from UIButton to a Tab Bar Item?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, segue

I have an app with a tab bar, which contains 5 tabs. I decided to have a "Home screen" instead of opening the app directly in the first tab. My home screen will contain a welcome message AND 5 buttons to segue directly to the wanted tab. Example: the 4th button will go to the 4th tab. After clicking one button, the home screen should never be seen again. The navigation mode will by the tab bar.

My Home View Controller 5 buttons and a reference to the Tab Bar Controller, to pass the button clicked. The Tab Bar Controller (`@interface TabBar : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>`) controls the screen where the 5 tabs starts. For some reasons, I can't get `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];`
 to work. I put it in `- (void)viewDidLoad`, but it does nothing.

Anyone has a clue why setSelectedItem isn't called?

**EDIT**: Look at that problem:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

NSLog(@"%i", self.tabBarController.selectedIndex);
```

At runtime, I get 0 as the result of NSLog... Why isn't the setter working?

Comment: Please post your code from the `-viewDidLoad:` method.

Comment: Nothing impressive in there, in fact it's the only way I know.

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    

[super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"didLoad");
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
}

Comment: Is the tab bar controller linked up with your view controllers in your storyboard correctly?

Comment: Well I don't have an IBOutlet from my Controller to the interface, because the TabBarController already has a tab bar by default. When I try to connect my class to the existing tab bar though, I gat a crash at runtime. For example, I tried to set the Tab Bar's delegate as the class itself, but the app crashes.

Comment: Is that supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can custom segue to the Tab Bar Controller and name the the segue (e.g. with "yourSegueName").

Than just call the UITabBarController  and setSelectedIndex at the desired tab-page:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueName"]){
    UITabBarController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [destController setSelectedIndex:3];
}
```

}