# TabBarController setSelectedIndex Function Does Not Work

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar

I have the same exact problem that appears in the following link

[How to segue from UIButton to a Tab Bar Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726620/how-to-segue-from-uibutton-to-a-tab-bar-item)

and unfortunately I couldn't find any solution till now

Notes :

1) I'm using iOS 5 with a storyboard -if make a difference-

2) I've tried `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectedItem:[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3]];` and also it does not work

3) I've tried to set IBOutlet for the tab bar and access it directly, but the app was crashed when I called `[self.myTabbar setSelectedItem:[self.myTabbar.items objectAtIndex:3]];` and got this error : Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OMG, it's like a magic, the solution is :

```
[(UITabBarController*)self.navigationController.topViewController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

I get the solution from the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10533414/1150618

Answer (score 4):

To start on a `tabBarItem` place in `AppDelegate`

```
[(UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController setSelectedIndex: 2];
```

so `RootViewController` automatically starts viewController